# Entire controller gets called on a function call

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I have a weird issue that Im facing.

There is an angular js controller and its corresponding html file.

Based on a button click in the html page, a function gets called which hides a certain div and shows another.

But what happens is, the button click function gets called but along with the entire js gets called(just like as if the page is loading for the 1st time). 
And I have some http call which I make on page load. Due to this http call the button click takes a lot of time to load. 
Some eg code:

/*JS Code */

```
controller config
$http.get('/getAllDetails',[]).success(function(data){
            $scope.details = data;
        })
        .error(function(data,status){
            alert("Something went wrong. Please try again");
        })
$scope.buttonclickFunction = function(){
 $scope.showSomeDiv = false;
 $scope.hideSomeDiv = true;
}
```

/*html code*/

```
<div ng-if = "showSomeDiv">
    <div ng-repeat = "detail in details">
     {{detail.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

/*The below div gets shown, but only after I get the response from the http call I am making in the beginning*/

```
<div ng-if = "hideSomeDiv">
    <p>This should be shown on button click</p>
</div>
```

Im relatively new to angular js. Hope someone can help me understand if this is how it is supposed to work or am I doing some novice mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have solved the issue.

The problem was, I had `ng-controller` defined in the form attribute. And as my html had 2 forms in it, the controller was getting initialized thrice (twice in html page and once on page load in the route config).

This was the reason why on button click the form was getting loaded and along with that the controller as well.

Hope this helps someone. :)